# Como converter html para CSV usando programação R

Tags: tabela-html

estou com o arquivo da lotofacil baixado em meu desktop e' uma tabela com os números históricos  da loto e esta em html  **file:///C:/Users/sergio/Desktop/D_LOTFAC.HTM**, eu uso programa R e gostaria de converte-lo para CSV, alguma sugestão?

Muito obrigado

Comment: Precisamente não sei dizer, da uma lida nesse link, talvez te de uma caminho para começar. http://rpubs.com/statshero/opinion-polls

Answer (score -1):

***Pessoal,***

***com as dicas que recebi consegui baixar e trabalhar com a planilha, segue o código:***

***O código necessita do pacote XML***

library(XML)

tf <- tempfile()

url <- "http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_lotfac.zip"

***Fiz o download usando modo "wb"***

download.file( url, tf, mode = "wb")

file.names <- unzip(tf)

***Após o unzip  a planilha de números estava no arquivo  D_LOTFAC.HTM***

urll <- "file:///C:/Users/sergio/Desktop/D_LOTFAC.HTM"

polls <- readHTMLTable(readLines(urll), which = 1, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

***A planilha continha muitos NA's então fiz uma limpeza com o complete.cases***

loto <- complete.cases(polls)

hist <- polls[loto,]

***Selecionei apenas as 17 primeiras colunas onde se encontram os numeros sorteados***

historico <- hist[,1:17]

***O resultado foi surpreendente!***

***Obrigado a todos***

***Sergio Simioni***